# Is is safe to use a stainless steel pan that has been cleaned with bleach (Comet)?

Tags: equipment, cleaning, stainless-steel

I have been cleaning my stainless steel pan with Comet for quite some time now and have only now come to know that I shouldn't be using bleach on stainless steel. If I clean it with dish soap and hot water, will that be enough? Is there anyway to make it reusable?

Answer (score 5):

- Can you smell bleach?
  If yes, rinse it & use it.
  If not, just use it.
- Is it stained?
  If not, just use it.
  If yes, you can remove the staining with bicarbonate paste made with water or Barkeeper's Friend.

Once any staining is gone, the natural coating [chromium oxide passive layer] will reform.
Just cook with it as normal.